# Best approach to add a case in a column for nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate-criteria

What is it the best way to add this query as projection in an nhibernate?

`CASE 
    WHEN account.firstname = '' AND account.lastname = '' 
        THEN email.EmailAddress
    ELSE account.firstname + ' ' + account.lastname
END`

Comment: Shouldn't this logic go in presentation layer ? Let hibernate retrieve what's there is database and handle this case scenario while rendering information

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
var accounts = session.QueryOver<Account>()
  .Select(Projections.Conditional(Restrictions.And(
            Restrictions.Eq("firstname", ""),
            Restrictions.Eq("lastname", "")),
              Projections.Concat(p.LastName, ", ", p.FirstName),
              Projections.Property(t => t.EmailAddress)))
  .List();
```